# kafka streams degraded performance at scale when sharing a thread from a core

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a kafka streams application which has a fairly decent topology and transformers etc . This application has an input topic , one state store (with changelog) and multiple output topics. The input topic has 300 partitions and we're currently running 150 pods with two kafka streams thread per pod. The application is orchestrated via kubernetes.

Scenario 1 : We've given a request CPU of 3 VCPU per pod and we've noticed kafka consumer lag building up during peak hours. However on observing the node metrics we see that the node CPU is not 100% and not bottlenecked. The PODs CPU usage does not go beyond 2 VCPU (as expected since there are only 2 threads )

Scenario 2 : We've given a request CPU of 4 VCPU per pod and we see no kafka consumer lag building up during peak hours. This is surprising to us since the POD CPU usage is still not going beyond 2 VCPU and the node CPU utilization is nowhere close to its peak.

In both scenario 1 & 2 the PODs are running in a 32 CPU 64 GB RAM nodepool. It is running on google cloud with N2D CPU type.

With all the above information we are suspecting that the kafka streams application is having a degraded performance due to the fact that N2D CPU types have 2 threads per core where each thread is one VCPU. This is done via a concept called [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) There have been various articles about how SMT can cause degraded performance for high scale workloads which have a lot of parallelism. Scenario 2 supports this theory because when we reserve 4 VCPU for each pod , we're essentially reserving 2 cores for each pod , this means that each kafka streams thread can get one core to itself.

This essentially means high throughput kafka streams applications will have degraded performance due to SMT (sharing of the thread in the core ) due to the high amount of parallelism that kafka streams optimizes the toplogy for.
I wanted to understand if this hypothesis is true and if anybody else is experiencing something like this and what can be done to improve performance?